# Создание вложенного экземпляра вложенного класса

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте! Возникла проблема с классами: есть два класса, один из них А содержит другой B. Сперва создается объект класса А, а он в свою очередь создает объект класса B, но объекту класса B нужны данные класса объекта класса А, который еще не создался... Вот такая вот санта барбара) Как можно провернуть такую штуку? И можно ли вообще такое сделать?
Спасибо.

Comment: Хорошо бы было какой-нибудь код увидеть. А так: либо сначала инициируйте "данные" класса А, а потом создавайте класс В, либо создайте класс В с параметрами по умолчанию, а потом их заполните данными класса А.

Comment: Делаю как вы сказали, но возникла ошибка: 

class B *s1;

class A{
s1->func();
};

class B{public:
void func();
};
error C2027: use of undefined type 'B'
error C2227: left of '->func' must point to class/struct/union/generic type В чем проблема?

Comment: Уточните вопрос. Что именно требуется?
В вопросе и в примере кода совершенно разные задачи.

- Класс A содержит объект класса B

- Класс B вложен в класс A.

- Класс A хочет вызывать методы класса B, до определения класса B

Comment: Ой, это я бред написал. Вот что требуется:


class A {

class B {

  public:

    void func(int a); // 1передать а из класса А

}*s1;

int a=5;

void fu(){

s1->func(int a); // 2вызвать функцию из класса B

}

};

 Сперва создать класс B, затем передать в него переменную а и вызвать в функции класса А функцию класса B;

Comment: Вот так работает. Ничего заумного тут нет. Или вы не статическую переменную хотите инициализировать в классе?
Порядок срабатывания

-конструктор A.

-fu() A

-func() B



    class A {
    public:
    
    class B{
    public:
    
    void func(int integer)
    {
    std::cout << "\nfunc B=" << integer; 
    }
    }*s1;
    
    int a;
    void fu()
    {
    std::cout << "\nfu()"; 
    s1->func(a); // 2вызвать функцию из класса B
    }
    
    A(){
    std::cout << "\nконструктор"; 
    a=5;
    }
    
    };

Answer (score 2):

> но обьекту класса B нужны данные класса обьекта класса А

Если имелось ввиду, что **обьекту** класса `B` нужны данные **обьекта** класса `А`, то это можно сделать через `pointers-to-members`:

```
template< typename Data, typename Owner >
inline LONG_PTR member_to_long( Data Owner::*member ){
    union{
        Data Owner::*   member;
        LONG_PTR    offset;
    }retval = { member };
    return retval.offset;
}
//
template< typename Data, typename Owner >
inline Data Owner::* long_to_member( LONG_PTR offset ){
    union{
        LONG_PTR    offset;
        Data Owner::*   member;
    }retval = { offset };
    return retval.member;
}
//
template< typename Data, typename Owner >
inline Owner Data::*reverse_member( Data Owner::*member ){
    return long_to_member< Owner, Data >( -member_to_long( member ) );
}
```

но с одним условием: `B` должен знать архитектуру класса `A`, т.е., по сути - он должен быть подклассом класса `A`:

```
class A{
    class B{
        int int_b;
        A*get_a( void ){ return &( this->*reverse_member( &A::b ) ); }
    public:    
        B( void ) : int_b( get_a()->int_a * 10 ){}
    };
    int int_a;
    B   b;
public:    
    A( int int_a ) : int_a( int_a ){}
};
```

> который еще не создался...

Если, опять же, имеется ввиду, что **объект** класса `A` содержит **объект** класса `B` (как в последнем примере), то `b` будет создан после того, как будет создан `a`.

p.s.: код писал в браузере, не проверял

Comment: А где можно про это почитать?

Comment: >А где можно про это почитать?

[`pointer-to-member`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8336763.aspx) - это спорная область в плане переносимости, поскольку, насколько я знаю, нет стандарта, предписывающего реализацию такого указателя. У Microsoft реализация ссылки-на-член-класса на протяжении нескольких поколений vs постоянна, поэтому я и предложил такой код. Что будет у других мне самому интересно.

Answer (score 1):

В классе А можно получить только доступ к указателю класса В

```
class B;

class A{
B * b;
};

class B{
};
```

и никак иначе

---

добавлено 13:39

вот вполне рабочий код

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class B;

class A{
B * b;
public:
    A();
};

class B{
};

A::A() { b = new B; }

int main(){

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Вариант 1: вызывать через глобальную функцию. объявив её заранее.

```
class B;
void вызвать_func();

class A
{

A()
{
вызвать_func();
}

};

class B
{
public: 
void func(){}; 
};

B b;

void вызвать_func()
{
b.func();
}
```

Вариант 2: объявить класс B перед классом A а реализовать его после.

```
class B
{
public: 
void func(); 
};

B * b;

class A
{
public:
A()
{
b->func();
}

};

void B::func(){};
```

Answer (score 0):

Всё оказалось как всегда просто до невозможности) Нужно было обьявить класс B вне класса А(до класса А), создать в классе B функции, не использующие данные класса А в нем, использующие только обьявить. Затем эти остальные функции(затрагивающие класс А) написать за классом А!!!
Вопрос снят! Всем спасибо!